# How to do a dynamoDB.scan() from Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am teaching myself Lambda and AWS services. I am simply trying to access everything in the APIGateway table called "Vocabulary" but I am following a tutorial that is not compatible with ES5 and according to the error I got earlier, it didnt like require for importing aws-sdk, but to change it to import instead.

I'm using my best knowledge in JS to go along with this but I'm hitting deadends everywhere.

```
import {DynamoDBClient} from '@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb';

const docClient = new DynamoDBClient({});

export const handler = async function(event, context, callback) {

  let scanningParameters = {
    TableName : 'Vocabulary'
  };

  docClient.scan(scanningParameters, 
      function(err, data){
          if (err) {
              callback(err, null);
          } else {
              callback(null, data.Items);
          }
      });
  };
```

The error I'm getting is

```
Response
{
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "errorMessage": "docClient.scan is not a function",
  "trace": [
    "TypeError: docClient.scan is not a function",
    "    at Runtime.handler (file:///var/task/index.mjs:11:13)",
    "    at Runtime.handleOnceNonStreaming (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1147:29)"
  ]
}
```

Thanks (Keep in mind, I know very little about all of this still)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Lambda with node runtime 18 you need to use the JS SDK V3, which has a syntax like the following, note it's a `send` command which is generic for all APIs.

```
import { DynamoDBClient, ScanCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb";

const client = new DynamoDBClient({});

export const handler = async function(event, context, callback) {
  
const command = new ScanCommand({
    TableName: "Vocabulary",
  });

  const response = await client.send(command);

  response.Items.forEach(function (item) {
    console.log(`${item}`);
  });
  return response;
};
```

Comment: Thank you. This looks very clear to me. I’m not at my desk right now but I trust this will work. I’ll check in an hour or so. Thanks